# Example of test plan

Tags: testing, test-plan

I have done some research and found test plan over 40 pages. It includes so many elements that it is difficult to keep track. Additionally, it is not provided any examples, just a description of the different tests such as acceptance test, system test, etc. If anyone have made some good and simple test plan for the development of a product and could share, so that I can gain inspiration with example would be very helpful.

Comment: You may want to clarify you desire a little more--are you looking for examples of *unit testing* and *test-driven development (TDD), *integration testing*, *acceptance testing*...? The list at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_testing might be helpful in finding the terms to narrow down what you are looking for.

Comment: Basically an an simple test plan which includes many of the test. Wikipedia page only have description of the test, not example provide. for instance: "user to to the page and log ut"

Answer (score 4):

yeah, i find that a pain to when i just want to do the thing, and people explain around it - im like "just bloody show me an example template i can rip off!"

this is why i write my articles with a pragmatic approach (e.g. [Writing a System Test Plan](http://pm4web.blogspot.com/2008/07/writing-system-test-plan.html))

its short, has an explanation of the reasoning behind the test structure, and gives the actual template

-- LM